# How to map numeric data into categories / bins in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

[image: SamplePandas]

It has around 3m rows. There are 3 kinds of `age_units`: Y, D, W  for years, Days & Weeks. Any individual over 1 year old has an age unit of Y and my first grouping I want is <2y old so all I have to test for in Age Units is Y...

I want to create a new column `AgeRange` and populate with the following ranges:

- <2
- 2 - 18
- 18 - 35
- 35 - 65
- 65+

so I wrote a function

```py
def agerange(values):
    for i in values:
        if complete.Age_units == 'Y':
            if complete.Age > 1 AND < 18 return '2-18'
            elif complete.Age > 17 AND < 35 return '18-35'
            elif complete.Age > 34 AND < 65 return '35-65'
            elif complete.Age > 64 return '65+'
        else return '< 2'
```

I thought if I passed in the dataframe as a whole, I would get back what I needed and then could create the column I wanted something like this:

```py
agedetails['age_range'] = ageRange(agedetails)
```

BUT when I try to run the first code to create the function I get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-124-cf39c7ce66d9>", line 4
    if complete.Age > 1 AND complete.Age < 18 return '2-18'
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Clearly it is not accepting the AND - but I thought I heard in class I could use AND like this?  I must be mistaken but then what would be the right way to do this?

So after getting that error, I'm not even sure the method of passing in a dataframe will throw an error either.  I am guessing probably yes.  In which case - how would I make that work as well?

I am looking to learn the best method, but part of the best method for me is keeping it simple even if that means doing things in a couple of steps...

Comment: great answer below by @jpp - also regards to your invalid syntax AND should be small letters `and` also after if statement condition you need to use `:` so it should be `if complete.Age > 1 and complete.Age < 18:  return '2-18'`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With Pandas, you should avoid row-wise operations, as these usually involve an inefficient Python-level loop. Here are a couple of alternatives.

#### Pandas: [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

As @JonClements suggests, you can use `pd.cut` for this, the benefit here being that your new column becomes a [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

You only need to define your boundaries (including `np.inf`) and category names, then apply `pd.cut` to the desired numeric column.

```
bins = [0, 2, 18, 35, 65, np.inf]
names = ['<2', '2-18', '18-35', '35-65', '65+']

df['AgeRange'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins, labels=names)

print(df.dtypes)

# Age             int64
# Age_units      object
# AgeRange     category
# dtype: object
```

#### NumPy: [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

`np.digitize` provides another clean solution. The idea is to define your boundaries and names, create a dictionary, then apply `np.digitize` to your Age column. Finally, use your dictionary to map your category names.

Note that for boundary cases the lower bound is used for mapping to a bin.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [99, 53, 71, 84, 84],
                   'Age_units': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']})

bins = [0, 2, 18, 35, 65]
names = ['<2', '2-18', '18-35', '35-65', '65+']

d = dict(enumerate(names, 1))

df['AgeRange'] = np.vectorize(d.get)(np.digitize(df['Age'], bins))
```

#### Result

```
   Age Age_units AgeRange
0   99         Y      65+
1   53         Y    35-65
2   71         Y      65+
3   84         Y      65+
4   84         Y      65+
```

Comment: Or... add `float('inf')` (or `np.inf`) to the end of `bins`, and then use: `pd.cut(df.Age, bins, labels=names)`... That way you'll get a categorical series instead of a string...

Comment: @jpp This is BRILLIANT!  Thank you for taking the trouble to provide such a clear and well thought through response, and adding in the bins/ pandas cut method with detail is the perfect icing on the cake.  This is the simplest most elegant approach, and I am certainly using it thank you.  I had seen somewhere in all the looking I was doing something about Bins - but hadn't figured out how to apply it, and certainly not how easy it would be!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This task can also be done using numpy methods. In particular, `numpy.select` can be used here to convert the numeric data into categorical data. It is very similar to the if-else ladder in the OP; only the conditions are in one list and the return values are in another list.

```py
import numpy as np
conds = [df['Age']<2, df['Age'].between(2, 18), df['Age'].between(19, 35), df['Age'].between(36, 65)]
names = ['<2', '2-18', '18-35', '35-65', '65+']
df['AgeRange'] = np.select(conds, names[:-1], names[-1])
```

Another method is `numpy.searchsorted`. In fact, under the hood, `pd.cut` implements this method as well. The basic idea is to find where each age would be inserted in `bins` to preserve order (which is essentially what binning is) and select the corresponding label from `names`.

```py
bins = [0, 2, 18, 35, 65, np.inf]
names = np.array(['<2', '2-18', '18-35', '35-65', '65+'])
df['AgeRange'] = names[np.searchsorted(bins, df['Age'])-1]
```