# Use a dictionary to key a range of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to create categories in a new column based on the values of another column. I can solve my basic problem by doing this:

```
range = {
    range(0, 5) : 'Below 5',
    range(6,10): 'between',
    range(11, 1000) : 'above'
}

df['range'] = df['value'].map(range)
```

In the final dictionary key I have chosen a large upper value for range to ensure it captures all the values I am trying to map. However, this seems an ugly hack and am wondering how to generalise this without specifying the upper limit. ie. if > 10 : 'above'.

Thanks

Comment: Think about using `apply`

Comment: Aye! I will give that a go!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping ranges of values in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098025/mapping-ranges-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe) Also, see [How to map numeric data into categories / bins in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382207/7851470)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you have a dataframe like this:

```
  range value
0   0     0
1   1     1
2   2     2
3   3     3
4   4     4
5   5     5
6   6     6
7   7     7
8   8     8
9   9     9
```

Then you can apply the following function to the column 'value':

```
def get_value(range):
    if range < 5:
        return 'Below 5'
    elif range < 10:
        return 'Between 5 and 10'
    else:
        return 'Above 10'

df['value'] = df.apply(lambda col: get_value(col['range']), axis=1)
```

To get the result you want.

Answer (score 5):

You could set all values first to 'above', and then use `map()` for the remaining options (thus with your `range` dict having only two items):

```
range = {
    range(0, 5) : 'Below 5',
    range(6,10): 'between',

}
df['range'] = 'above'
df['range'] = df['value'].map(range)
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the hints. I see I can achieve the same with:

```
df['range'] = df['value'].map(range).fillna('above')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach using [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), where you specify a list of boolean conditions, and a list of choices:

```
import numpy as np 

# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 3, 6, 8, 20, 10000000]})

condlist = [
    df['value'].lt(5),
    df['value'].between(5, 10),
    df['value'].gt(10)]

choicelist = ['Below 5', 'between', 'above']

df['out'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
print(df)
```

[out]

```
      value      out
0         1  Below 5
1         3  Below 5
2         6  between
3         8  between
4        20    above
5  10000000    above
```

---

Another idea would be to use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with `bins` and `labels` parameters specified:

```
df['out'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins=[-np.inf, 5, 10, np.inf],
                   labels=['below', 'between', 'above'])

      value      out
0         1    below
1         3    below
2         6  between
3         8  between
4        20    above
5  10000000    above
```

Answer (score 3):

[pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) accepts also `function` as first argument, so you could do:

```
def fun(x):
    if x in range(0, 5):
        return 'Below 5'
    elif x in range(6, 10):
        return 'between'
    elif x >= 11:
        return 'above'
```

then:

```
df['range'] = df['value'].map(fun)
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Now for replacing `run` with a lambda function with a nested ternary comparison, to one-line everything. I guess `df['range'] = df['value'].map(lambda x: 'Below 5' if in x range(0, 5) else ('between' if x in (range(6, 10) else 'above'))` could do that.

Comment: @0 0: for me one-line nested `if`s are not very readable. If I would have fit into 1 line in this case AT ANY PRICE then I would rather do: `f = lambda x:('Below 5','between','above')[(x>=5)+(x>=11)]`

Comment: Also nice.I was definitely going for obfuscated Python one-liners. Luckily, in Python,`True + True == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df['range'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins = [0, 5, 10, 1000], labels = ["below 5", "between", "above"])
```

Comment: That still suffers from setting a rather arbritrary upper limit (one could use `max(df['value'])` of course.