# Lambda apply include NaN values in new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am creating a new column in a dataframe based on a conditional function. In the column I am mapping from, there are multiple NaN values. If a NaN value is present in the original column, I also want this to be present in my new column. As an example, my starting point is this:

```
Original
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   Nan
7   8
8   9
9   10
```

Here is a sample of the code I initially run which gives the following result (clearly):

```
def get_value(range):
    if range < 2:
        return 'Below 2'
    elif range < 8:
        return 'Between 2 and 8'
    else:
        return 'Above 8'

df_sample['new_col'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x: get_value(x['Original']), axis=1)
```

```
Original    new_col
0   1.0 Below 2
1   2.0 Between 2 and 8
2   3.0 Between 2 and 8
3   4.0 Between 2 and 8
4   5.0 Between 2 and 8
5   6.0 Between 2 and 8
6   NaN Above 8
7   8.0 Above 8
8   9.0 Above 8
9   10.0    Above 8
```

Here, index 6 should show NaN.

I have tried including elif range == np.Nan: in my function but this didn't work.

I then tried the following based on a recommendation on Stackoverflow:

```
df_sample['new_col'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x: get_value(x) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x['Original']))) else x, axis = 1)
```

But this returns an error at the first NaN index in my dataframe.

Comment: This is not a recommended way of doing this, but if you insist then you could add `if np.isnan(range):
        return np.nan` condition

Comment: @ChrisA do you mind explaining why this is not recommended? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Déjà vu here, but following on from my [last solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510900/10201580), just add `default` for where no condition is met:

```
import numpy as np 

condlist = [
    df['Original'].lt(2),
    df['Original'].lt(8),
    df['Original'].ge(8)]

choicelist = ['Below 2', 'Between 2 and 8', 'Above 8']

df['new_col'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
print(df)
```

[out]

```
   Original          new_col
0       1.0          Below 2
1       2.0  Between 2 and 8
2       3.0  Between 2 and 8
3       4.0  Between 2 and 8
4       5.0  Between 2 and 8
5       6.0  Between 2 and 8
6       NaN              nan
7       8.0          Above 8
8       9.0          Above 8
9      10.0          Above 8
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, sorry I got stuck with this and thought it would be best to create a new question

Answer (score 1):

In general, do not use `apply`. In thise case, `cut` is a much better choice:

```
pd.cut(df.Original, [-np.inf, 2, 8, np.inf],
       labels = ['below 2', 'between 2 and 8', 'above 8'],
       right=False)
```

Output:

```
0            below 2
1    between 2 and 8
2    between 2 and 8
3    between 2 and 8
4    between 2 and 8
5    between 2 and 8
6                NaN
7            above 8
8            above 8
9            above 8
Name: Original, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [below 2 < between 2 and 8 < above 8]
```

Comment: I've already suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510900/10201580)... don't think he's interested

Answer (score 1):

To comment on your code :

As you're using the else statement, everything not bellow 8 will be display as 'above 8'. Even if in your original dataset you have the string 'hello world'.

To stay as simple as your code you could do :

```
def get_value(range):
    if range < 2:
        return 'Below 2'
    elif range < 8:
        return 'Between 2 and 8'
    elif range >= 8:
        return 'Above 8'
    else:
        return np.nan
```