# Counting values for each unique entity in a pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, counting

I have a csv file with 3 columns. users, text and labels. each user has multiple texts and labels. 
i want to know the label with the highest frequency of occurrence in order to determine the category of each user.

I have tried:

```
for i in df['user'].unique():
    print (df['class'].value_counts())
```

which gives returns the same values shown below for all users

```
4    3062
1    1250
0     393
3     281
2      13
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

I also tried

```
for h in df['user'].unique():
    g = Counter(df['class'])
    print (g)
```

and got

```
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
Counter({4: 3062, 1: 1250, 0: 393, 3: 281, 2: 13})
```

here is the sample data
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzcUW.jpg)
Please Help

Comment: Sample data and expected output makes it even clearer .

Comment: so you just want to count the labels for each user? maybe `groupby` can help you

Comment: sorry man. i have now included the sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting values by group, you can use `groupby` with `pd.value_counts`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2],
                   [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3]],
                  columns=['user', 'class'])

res = df.groupby('user')['class'].apply(pd.value_counts).reset_index()
res.columns = ['user', 'class', 'count']

print(res)

   user  class   count
0     1      1       3
1     1      2       2
2     1      3       1
3     2      3       3
4     2      2       2
5     2      1       1
```

Comment: excellent answer. but how do i write conditional statements to access the values for count. i.e. if the count value for a class > 200 then category =  0 or 1 or 2....???

Comment: That's a separate question, but you can use `pd.cut` or `np.digitize` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382340/9209546).

Comment: thanks for your quick and accurate responses and i have also looked at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers