# The pandas equivalent of 'if' 'else' conditionals to add calculated column to df

Tags: python, pandas

the below table counts unique words in a text (German text of Hamlet in this case).

Using Pandas I would like to add a column['frequency'] that prints one of three answers.

- If the value in the 'count' column **is <=10** the frequency is
  'infrequent'
- If the value in the 'count' column **is >10** the frequency is
  'frequent'
- If the value in the 'count' column **is 1** the frequency is 'unique'

I am new to pandas so I initially thought I would have to use a 'for' loop and 'if' 'else'. Of course, that didn't work for me and after reading around this I see you can just use .loc[] instead. It's much cleaner.

I'll put the answer below in case anyone else needs this setting out really clearly.  Here's the table I'm working with before-

```
      count                 word  length
0     67223                            0
1         7               deinen       6
2         1          überwachsen      11
3         3                 them       4
4         2            fortunens       9
5         1              flammen       7
6         1    ersäuentsezlichen      17
7         2              alleino       7
8         1             empfehle       8
9         1  beschulöffentlicher      19
10        1         unterthänige      12
11        1                   pr       2
12        1       zurükzutreiben      14
13       38                   wo       2
14        1          schadhaften      11
15        1               ddiese       6
16        1         zurükhaltend      12
17        1                 laim       4
18        1               agents       6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative to this using DataFrame.apply:

```
def frequer(wordcnt):
    if wordcnt == 1: return 'unique'
    elif wordcnt >10: return 'frequent'
    else: return 'infrequent'

df['freq'] = df.apply(lambda x: frequer(x['count']),axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is a fantastic use case for `pd.cut`:

```
pd.cut(df['count'], 
       bins=[-np.inf, 1, 10, np.inf], 
       labels=['unique', 'infrequent', 'frequent'])

0       frequent
1     infrequent
2         unique
3     infrequent
4     infrequent
5         unique
6         unique
7     infrequent
8         unique
9         unique
10        unique
11        unique
12        unique
13      frequent
14        unique
15        unique
16        unique
17        unique
18        unique
Name: count, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [unique < infrequent < frequent]
```

The disadvantage with `np.select` in the other answer is that you will need to evaluate all conditions before selection, and will not scale as well with more conditions.

Answer (score 4):

For multiple conditions, consider using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conditions = [data['count'] == 1, data['count'] > 10, data['count'] <= 10]
choices = ['unique', 'frequent', 'infrequent']

data['frequency'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

The order of your `conditions` is important, as you do not want `data['count'] <= 10` to include a count of `1`.

You may also wish to consider `pd.cut` or `np.digitize`, see also [How to map numeric data into categories / bins in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382207/9209546).

Comment: Excellent as always, can you guide me to a good web link for numpy please, not good there. thanks

Comment: The `data['count'] == 1` should be before `data['count'] <= 10`, otherwise `count == 1` is also classified as "infrequent" (when it should be "unique"). The order of the conditions matter.

Comment: I am not worried about that since I am not the OP. :) I have been a keen follower of both of you  @coldspeed if you and jpp can share some good numpy links , that would be very helpful.

Comment: @anky_91 [Here is a hopefully instructive starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a4909087%20%5bnumpy%5d%20is%3aa) :) As for how/why I learned, it was mostly out of a requirement to speed up existing pandas code (doing the same thing with numpy is usually faster than pandas because of less overhead). Docs, and other, older answers mainly.

Comment: @coldspeed, Good point, thanks. We can just change the order of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

After - please ignore the first row, though, which just gives the overall number of unique words in the text.

```
data.loc[data["count"] > 10,  "frequency"] = "frequent"
data.loc[data["count"] <= 10, "frequency"] = "infrequent"
data.loc[data["count"] == 1,  "frequency"] = "unique"
```

result:

```
  count                 word  length   frequency
0     67223                            0    frequent
1         7               deinen       6  infrequent
2         1          überwachsen      11      unique
3         3                 them       4  infrequent
4         2            fortunens       9  infrequent
5         1              flammen       7      unique
6         1    ersäuentsezlichen      17      unique
7         2              alleino       7  infrequent
8         1             empfehle       8      unique
9         1  beschulöffentlicher      19      unique
10        1         unterthänige      12      unique
11        1                   pr       2      unique
12        1       zurükzutreiben      14      unique
13       38                   wo       2    frequent
```

Comment: All these answers have been great! I gave the solution I used when I posted the question. However my method was really basic, and all these other methods are really useful to know

Comment: In that case, you can accept your own answer, if you prefer it to all the others posted here.

Comment: thanks for the tip; I don't prefer it over any of the others, but may as well