# Grouping numerical values in categories

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, split, data-science

I have numeric data within Student marks and I would like to group them into 3 categories A, B and C.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Adel',  3.5),
                   ('Betty',  2.75),
                   ('Djamel',  2.10),
                   ('Ramzi',  1.75),
                   ('Alexa', 3.15)],
                  columns=('Name', 'GPA'))
```

I tried function `pd.cut()` but it didn't lead to wanted result .

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `pd.cut`:

```
df = df.sort_values('GPA')

df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['GPA'], bins=3, labels = ['A','B','C'])

     Name   GPA bins
3   Ramzi  1.75    A
2  Djamel  2.10    A
1   Betty  2.75    B
4   Alexa  3.15    C
0    Adel  3.50    C
```

Answer (score 1):

In a recent research, a PSO was implemented to classify students under unknown number of groups. PSO showed improved capabilities compared to GA. I think that all you need is the specific research.

The paper is: Forming automatic groups of learners using particle swarm optimization for applications of differentiated instruction

You can find the paper here: https://doi.org/10.1002/cae.22191

Perhaps the researchers could guide you through researchgate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338078753

You just need to remove the technic from automatic number of groups

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution :

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'GPA': [99, 53, 71, 84, 84],
                   'Name': ['Betty', 'Djamel', 'Ramzi', 'Alexa', 'Adel']})

bins = [0, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
names = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', "A"]

d = dict(enumerate(names, 1))

df['Rank'] = np.vectorize(d.get)(np.digitize(df['GPA'], bins))
```

thanks to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382207/how-to-map-numeric-data-into-categories-bins-in-pandas-dataframe).