# How to use pandas apply on certain columns with args

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a `pandas dataframe` with columns `val_min` and `val_max` below:

```
df 
   val_min  val_max
0   1001.0  1500.0
3   401.0   500.0
4   401.0   500.0
5   401.0   500.0
6   501.0   600.0
```

Now I am trying to create a new column using these two columns with `pandas apply` function and create a new column based on some certain functions defined in my function, see my attempt below:

```
def get_range(df, val_min, val_max, new_col):
    if df[val_min] <500 & df[val_max]<500:
        df[new_col] = "<500"
        
    elif df[val_min] >500 & df[val_max]<=1000:
        df[new_col] = "500 - 1000"
        
    elif df[val_min] >1000 & df[val_max]<=2000:
        df[new_col] = "1000 - 2000"
        
    elif df[val_min] >2000 & df[val_max]<=5000:
        df[new_col] = "2000 - 5000"
        
    elif df[val_min] >5000 & df[val_max]<=7500:
        df[new_col] = "5000 - 7500"
        
    elif df[val_min] >7500 & df[val_max]<=10000:
        df[new_col] = "7500 - 10000"
        
    elif df[val_min] >10000 & df[val_max]<=12000:
        df[new_col] = "10000 - 12000"
        
    elif df[val_min] >12000 & df[val_max]<=15000:
        df[new_col] = "12000 - 15000"
        
    elif df[val_min] >15000 & df[val_max]>15000:
        df[new_col] = ">15000"

df["new_col"] = df[["val_min", "val_max"]].apply(get_range, axis=1)
```

Comment: can you post the sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: I have updated the question for your review

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382207/how-to-map-numeric-data-into-categories-bins-in-pandas-dataframe) could be of some help

Comment: No, it doesnt they are two different things. I am not using a cut function here. pandas apply should fix this. I am dealing with two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the function's structure to this:

```
def get_range(x):
    val_min=x.val_min
    val_max=x.val_max
    if (val_min <500)&(val_max<500):
        return "<500"
        
    elif (val_min >500)&(val_max<=1000):
        return  "500 - 1000"
    ...
```

And then apply this to the dataframe:

```
df["new_col"] = df.apply(get_range, axis=1)
```

---

So, for example:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_range(x):
    val_min=x.val_min
    val_max=x.val_max
    if (val_min <500 )&(val_max<500):
        return "<500"
        
    elif (val_min>500)&(val_max<=1000):
        return  "500 - 1000"
        

df = pd.DataFrame({'val_min':[600, 34], 'val_max':[800, 340]})

df["new_col"] = df.apply(get_range, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   val_min  val_max     new_col
0      600      800  500 - 1000
1       34      340        <500
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately., I get the following error: `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: You should change `val_min <500 & val_max<500` to `(val_min <500)&(val_max<500)` or to `(val_min<500) and (val_max<500)`. Just changed in my answer

Comment: @Pythonista, you can also factorize code by defining the variable that's is going to be returned and, return it at the end of the code, instead of returning it in each if statement. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: oh, that's a fantastic idea! I love it! Than you! :D

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `np.select`

```py
import numpy as np

cases = [(df.val_min < 500) & (df.val_max < 500),
           (df.val_min > 500) & (df.val_max <= 1000),
           (df.val_min > 1000) & (df.val_max <= 2000),
           (df.val_min > 2000) & (df.val_max <= 5000),
           (df.val_min > 5000) & (df.val_max <= 7500),
           (df.val_min > 7500) & (df.val_max <= 10000),
           (df.val_min > 10000) &( df.val_max <= 12000),
           (df.val_min > 12000) &( df.val_max <= 15000),
            (df.val_min > 15000) &( df.val_max > 15000)]


values = ['<500',
          '500 - 1000',
          '1000 - 2000',
          '2000 - 5000',
          '5000 - 7500',
          '7500 - 10000',
          '10000 - 12000',
          '12000 - 15000',
          '>15000']


df['new_col'] = np.select(cases, values, default='')
print(df)
```

Output

```
   val_min  val_max      new_col
0   1001.0   1500.0  1000 - 2000
1    401.0    500.0             
2    401.0    500.0             
3    401.0    500.0             
4    501.0    600.0   500 - 1000
```

Comment: very insightful! Thanks.

Comment: by the way why the empty spaces?

Comment: val_max is 500. so, none of the ranges are satisfied per your problem description. The `default` kicks in which is an empty string. Should the question be revised to `if df[val_min] <500 & df[val_max]<=500:` ? @Pythonista

Comment: Great stuff! I found it very insightful.

Comment: @Pythonista Good to know. You still haven't answered my previous comment.

Comment: Oh, I already fixed that at my end. Thats fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

could you try this ? it might work

```
def get_range(df, val_min, val_max, new_col):
    if val_min <500 & val_max <500:
        return "<500"

    elif val_min >500 & val_max <=1000:
        return "500 - 1000"
[...]

df["new_col"] = df[["val_min", "val_max"]].apply(get_range, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply` with `lambda`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"val_min":list(range(10,1000,100)),"val_max":list(range(20,2000,200))})


def get_range(val_min, val_max):
    if val_min <500 & val_max<500:
        new_col = "<500"
        
    elif val_min >500 & val_max<=1000:
        new_col = "500 - 1000"
        
    elif val_min >1000 & val_max<=2000:
        new_col = "1000 - 2000"
        
    elif val_min >2000 & val_max<=5000:
        new_col = "2000 - 5000"
        
    elif val_min >5000 & val_max<=7500:
        new_col = "5000 - 7500"
        
    elif val_min >7500 & val_max<=10000:
        new_col = "7500 - 10000"
        
    elif val_min >10000 & val_max<=12000:
        new_col = "10000 - 12000"
        
    elif val_min >12000 & val_max<=15000:
        new_col = "12000 - 15000"
        
    elif val_min >15000 & val_max>15000:
        new_col = ">15000"
    return new_col

df["new_col"] = df[["val_min", "val_max"]].apply(lambda row :get_range(*row), axis=1)
```

print(df)

```
   val_min  val_max     new_col
0       10       20        <500
1      110      220        <500
2      210      420        <500
3      310      620  500 - 1000
4      410      820  500 - 1000
5      510     1020  500 - 1000
6      610     1220  500 - 1000
7      710     1420  500 - 1000
8      810     1620  500 - 1000
9      910     1820  500 - 1000
[Finished in 1.8s]
```