# Creating a function which creates a new column based on values in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like -

```
ID     Min_Value    Max_Value
1       0           0.10562
2    0.10563        0.50641
3      0.50642      1.0
```

I have another data frame that contains `Value` as a column. I want to create a new column in second data frame which returns `ID` when `Value` is between `Min_Value` and `Max_Value` for a given `ID` as above data frame. I can use `if-else` conditions but number of ID's are large and code becomes too bulky. Is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: Looks like [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382207/how-to-map-numeric-data-into-categories-bins-in-pandas-dataframe) solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just join/merge it into one DataFrame, using "between" function you can choose right indexes which will be located in the second DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {"Min_Value": [0, 0.10563, 0.50642], 
        "Max_Value": [0.10562, 0.50641, 1.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                  index=[1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Value": [0, 0.1, 0.58]}, index=[1,2,3])

df = df.join(df2)

mask_between_values = df['Value'].between(df['Min_Value'], df['Max_Value'], inclusive="neither")

# This is the result
df2[mask_between_values]

1   0.00
3   0.58
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two dataframes df and new_df. You want to assign a new column as 'new_column' into new_df dataframe. The value of 'Value' column must be between 'Min_Value' and 'Max_Value' from df dataframe. Then this code may help you.

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'Max_Value'] > new_df.loc[i,'Value'] and df.loc[i,'Min_value'] < new_df.loc[i,'Value']:
        new_df.loc[i,'new_column'] = df.loc[i, 'ID']
```

Comment: Got two syntax errors with this: missing ' following both Max_Value and Min_Value. Once those were fixed, got error: `ValueError: 3 is not in range`. (There were four rows in my `new_df` data.)

Comment: You got this error because you df dataframe has only 3 rows. New_df's length is greater than your df's length. You can use df instead of new_df for loop iteration.

Comment: I have edited the code. Check this out. Please use lowest length of dataframe for loop iteration so that you don't get Valueerror.

Comment: It still doesn't appear to do what I think the OP is requiring. If I use this input data (for new_df) `valuesData = pd.DataFrame([0.55, 0.123, 0.9, 0.3], columns=["Value"])` then it ends up with NaN values for the 1st and last items in new_df, and instead of producing a set of ID numbers, it just duplicates the Value numbers for the 2nd and 3rd rows.

Comment: I understood wrong firstly. I thought you want those data which is between Min_Values and Max_Values. But you just want the ID. I have edited the code. Please check this out